# tkinter Scale Widget - Return to center when not being used?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Is it possible to make the Scale Widget return to the center of the scale when it is not in use?

Currently, if I click and drag the scale widget to one side, it will remain in that position when I unclick the slider. Is it possible to make the slider return to the center when it is unclicked / no longer being dragged?

Current code to work on:

```
w = Scale(master, from_=0, to=1, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=some_function)
w.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to bind to the event `<ButtonRelease-`>, which will trigger when you release the mouse button. You can then call the `set` method to set the value to whatever you want.

For example:

```
self.scale = tk.Scale(...)
self.scale.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.reset_scale)
...
def reset_scale(self, event):
    self.scale.set(0)
```